# Static class vars type definition in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have some class named **myClass**, and following structure in there:

```
class myClass
{
    static $foo;

    public static function init()
    {
        self::$foo = new bar();
    }
}
```

How can I make phpstorm define **myClass::$foo** as **bar**'s object in the rest of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **[PHPDoc](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html)**.

```
class myClass
{
    /**
     * @var bar $foo - Holds a bar object.
     */
    static $foo;
}
```

Comment: In PHP, in that case, I don't think there is a point "initializing" to `null` since class members are default-initialized to `null` already. You're doing in 7 characters what I do in 0. ;-)

Comment: @netcoder: Yes, but in case something weren't clear enough for a different developer, he'll see (if he's a decent one), that $foo is supposed to be an object instantly in my code, where yours will not. Also, what if tomorrow PHP will decide that in PHP6, all class members will be initialized to `false`?

Comment: How does `null` initialization define that `$foo` is an object? If initialization was mandatory it would yield an error, or at least an E_STRICT one if it was considered a bad practice not to. It wouldn't make *any* sense at all to initialize something to `false`, considering what `null` actually means.

Comment: @netcoder: In **decent** languages, NULL signifies a pointer to an object which doesn't exist (a.k.a the NULL object). Also, initialization is not mandatory, it's good practice. Bad practices (sadly) don't throw any errors.

Comment: You're taking a simple comment to a very different level here. i.e.: I wasn't aware that PHP handled pointers. I wasn't aware that `null` pointers pointed to objects, and apparently you don't find PHP a decent language... interesting. I don't think it can be considered bad practice either, because it doesn't have *any* bad effects. My point is: I'm just saying.

Comment: @netcoder: It's alright :D ([See here](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)), what I mean is, one should always initialize a variable with something, even though it's initialized by default, that action is transparent and unclear to the naked eye.

Comment: @Truth seems doesn't work for me. In "structure" widnow my vars still has undefinded type. Do I need to install some plugin for phpstorm?

Comment: Oh, got it. There is should be "@property", not "@var". Thanks.

Comment: @Hast: Edited. That's weird because the `@var` was actually generated automatically by my PHP storm, and it worked for me :o. But whatever works for you :D

Comment: @Truth lol no, sorry, I did something wrong. "@var" is the right tag :D

Comment: @Truth but why \bar, not just bar? What that backslash means?

Comment: @Hast actually I have no idea.  That's the way php storm generates it for me. Works without one too though.

Comment: @Raveren: most users (me included) would prefer if you asked them first in comments before you make a substantial edit to their answer. I'll accept the edit, but please be more communicative.

Comment: Well I *did* leave the answer intact.

Comment: @Raveren: Not really, you removed a part which was part of my intention as an answer. I don't mind improvements to my answer, but please discuss it with me first.